# nvim - return a portion of the matched pattern (capture group)?

Tags: regex, variables, neovim, one-liner

**Data:**

```
line 1 = 1232
line 2 == 1456
line 3=2345
```

**Expected output**

```
line 1=1232
line 2==1456
line 3=2345
```

This is in a [nvim](/questions/tagged/nvim) editor & I want to [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) remove the spaces as mentioned above. I want to use something like this:

:'<,'>s/ =+ /*variable that returns the matched pattern except spaces*/g

Is there any 'variable that returns the matched pattern. except spaces' in **nvim** or **vim** that I can use to achieve this with the one-liner?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'variable the returns the matched pattern' does not make any sense. Do you want to remove whitespace around `=`?

Comment: @svlasov Yes, remove the white spaces, for both ' = ' & ' == '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a capture group to capture 1 or more times an equals sign.

It is not called a variable, but you use a backreference `\1` in the replacement, that holds the matched value of capture group 1.

The capture group is denoted with the escaped parenthesis, and the quantifier for 1 or more times is the escaped plus sign.

In vim:

```
:'<,'>s/ \(=\+\) /\1/g
```

According to the comments, in `nvim` without the escapes:

```
:'<,'>s/ (=+) /\1/g
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. I knew there would be something like this but didn't know the right jargon **CAPTURE GROUP**. For my setup (nvim in VSCODE, in a .ipynb file), this works: `:'<,'>s/ (=+) /\1/g`